# Cannot inherit from final 'com.example.mycountryapp.databinding.FragmentFeedBinding' and 'FragmentFeedBinding()' has private access in

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, androidx

Feed Fragment

```
class FeedFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var viewModel : FeedViewModel
private val countryAdapter = CountryAdapter(arrayListOf())

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false)


}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FeedViewModel::class.java)
    viewModel.refreshData()

    countryList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    countryList.adapter = countryAdapter

    observeLiveData()
}
private fun observeLiveData() {
    viewModel.countries.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { countries->
        countries?.let {
            countryList.visibility=View.VISIBLE
            countryAdapter.updateCountryList(countries)
        }
    })
    viewModel.countryError.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { error->
        error?.let {
            if(it) {
                countryerror.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                countryerror.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    })
    viewModel.countryLoading.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { loading->
        loading?.let {
            if (it) {
                countryLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                countryList.visibility = View.GONE
                countryerror.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                countryLoading.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    })

}
```

}

my Country Fragment

```
class CountryFragment : Fragment() {
private var countryUuid = 0
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_country, container, false)

}
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        countryUuid = CountryFragmentArgs.fromBundle(it).countryUuid
    }
}
```

}

my feed viewmodel

```
class FeedViewModel : ViewModel() {
val countries = MutableLiveData<List<Country>>()
val countryError = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
val countryLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()

fun refreshData() {

    val country = Country("Turkey","Asia","Ankara","TRY","Turkish","www.ss.com")
    val country2 = Country("France","Europe","Paris","EUR","French","www.ss.com")
    val country3 = Country("Germany","Europe","Berlin","EUR","German","www.ss.com")

    val countryList = arrayListOf<Country>(country,country2,country3)

    countries.value = countryList
    countryError.value = false
    countryLoading.value = false
}
```

}

I am getting this error in java(generated)-> data binding->fragmentCountryBinding, fragmentFeed Binding, fragmentItemBinding parts of the application. I don't know how to solve this problem, I made databinding true in gradle.build part, but I am still facing these problems, if you know how to solve it and help me I would be very grateful.
Error is Cannot inherit from final 'com.example.mycountryapp.databinding.FragmentFeedBinding'
second error 'FragmentCountryBinding()' has private access in 'com.example.mycountryapp.databinding.FragmentCountryBinding'

_
[This my CountryFragment.xml][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkrL5.png

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryCapital"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/countryName"
        android:text="Country Capital"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryRegion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/countryCapital"
        android:text="Country Region"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryCurrency"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/countryRegion"
        android:text="Country Currency"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp">

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryLanguage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/countryCurrency"
        android:text="Country Language"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp">

    </TextView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where have you declared these things?
                countryLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                countryList.visibility = View.GONE
                countryerror.visibility = View.GONE

Comment: I declared it in my FeedFragment. When I start my application, the feedfragment will start with the navigation and I will show my items in the feed fragment. I just observe them, for example if there is no data I do the loading operation visibility.

Comment: Can you update country fragment xml?

Comment: ok it's here image+code, the end of the code is again with the layout